# Flutter: disable screenshot and screen recording for windows

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-windows

I am making a Flutter app and I need to make sure the user is not able to capture screenshots of the app (any screen). Is there any way to achieve this in windows applications

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot prevent the user from taking a screenshot! Even if in the future Windows gave us APIs to disallow screenshots, a user can still take their phone and take a photo of the screen with their phones.

If you have sensitive information on the screen which you want to protect, it's best to go about that in a different way.